# In R, can you allow a user to import namespace from only some functions?

Tags: r, namespaces, package

Say I have an R package with lots of functions. I want the user to be able to select which functions they import.

Basically, I have functions grouped into use cases. Say there are 50 functions from group A, and 30 functions from group B, with groups C, D, and E, etc. I don't want to export all the functions and overload the namespace with 500 functions (95% of which are not needed) -- in one script I may use functions from group A and B, in another script from group B and D. Can I allow the user to only import subsets of the functions defined in the package? I haven't been able to figure this out from reading the docs.

The obvious answer is that these should be separate packages; but I don't really want to do that, since there is a logical connection between them, they communicate with (and use) each other, and it would make maintaining them harder.

The poor man's way (that I currently use) is that each group of functions is in a separate file, and then I just source the files I need. But I'd like this to be in a package properly.

Any way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: What's the problem with exporting all the functions?

Comment: @nicola Just wanting to not pollute the user's namespace with hundreds of functions they will never use, if I can avoid it...

Comment: Functions in a package are stored in a dedicated environment and this can hardly be defined "pollution". They don't appear in the global environment. The `base` package may contain more than a thousand functions, most of them never used by an average user. I don't think that those functions pollute something. I can't really see the disadvantage of having a package with many functions.

Comment: These would be functions exported by the package, so they would appear in the global environment. I'm not talking about unexported functions -- those are obviously no problem. In any case, the question is still a valid one -- is it possible?

Comment: Again, exported functions of a package _do not_ belong to the global environment. Try `require(data.table)` and then `ls()`. Do you see some function from the `data.table` package? You would see them if you try `ls(envir=environment(data.table))`. As for your question, I don't think you can dynamically change the namespace of a package.

Comment: Right, I guess I mean search path. they are in the search path, right?

Comment: Yes. Keep also in mind that the `:::` operator let you "see" and use any function of a package (exported or not). Try for instance to digit the name of your package followed by `:::` and then press tab. You will see also the not exported functions. My two cents: user won't be bothered by the presence of functions he will never use and they are not polluting anything. In my opinion your issue is not a problem and probably doesn't have a solution (sensibly, since it's not a problem).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `NAMESPACE` file in the top level package directory. Read about all the details here [writing R extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces)

Comment: I know how to write R packages and NAMESPACE files... please take another look at the question...